# Spring Validator and Thymeleaf - Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('*')"

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to validate form's fields and I get an error that I have failed to resolve.

**myForm** is a form that contains an object (a filter) called **filtro** that extends another filter (the base filter). And, I'm trying to validate the inherited fields of myFilter.

**HTML**

```
<form th:object="${myForm}" method="post">
    <div style="padding-top: 15px;">
        <input type="text" th:field="${myForm.filtro.ricercaBaseCup.descrizione}" th:errorclass="fieldError"/> 
    </div>              
    <div padding-top: 15px;">
        <input type="text" th:field="${myForm.filtro.ricercaBaseGeografico.descrizione}" th:errorclass="fieldError"/>
    </div>
    <!--error messages-->
    <ul th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*')}" style="padding:0px; color:red">
        <li class='errorClass' th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('*')}" th:text="${err}"></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm form,
                              BindingResult bindingResult, 
                              Model model){


    //Validation
    new MyFormValidator().validate(new Object[]{form}, bindingResult);
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        bindingResult.getFieldError();
        return rootPath;
    }
```

**VALIDATOR**

```
public class MyFormValidator implements Validator{

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return MyForm .class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    Object[] obj = (Object[])obj;
    MyForm form = (MyForm)obj[0];

    if(form.getFiltroBase().getRicercaBaseCup().getDescrizione() != null && form.getFiltroBase().getRicercaBaseCup().getDescrizione().length() < 15){
        errors.rejectValue("filtro.ricercaBaseCup.descrizione", "gestOperativita.codCup.nonValido");
    }else if(form.getFiltroBase().getRicercaBaseCup().getDescrizione() == null){
        errors.rejectValue("filtro.ricercaBaseCup.descrizione", "gestOperativita.codCup.isEmpty");
    }

    if(form.getFiltroBase().getRicercaBaseGeografico().getDescrizione() == null){
        errors.rejectValue("filtro.ricercaBaseGeografico.descrizione", "gestOperativita.Ente.isEmpty");
    }
}

}
```

After `return rootPath;` instruction I refresh the html fragment containing the error messages but..

When I try it I get this:

> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#fields.hasErrors('*')"
>   (/controllaDocFinanziaria/gestioneOperativita:86) 23:23:58,603 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MutuiBEI].[dispatcher]]
>   (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet dispatcher threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hi, how are you trying to update the fragment containing the error messages?

Comment: @Periklis with jQuery

Comment: the /search is an ajax call from the form?

Comment: @Periklis I have a button in the form where I bind it with a jQuery ajax function